# Fill union with a char array member

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I have a C union with numerous fields which will very likely have different sizes across different platforms:

```
union foo {
    int a;
    wchar_t b;
    bar *c;
    baz d;
}
```

Now I want to add a char array to this union that's exactly as big as I can make it without it causing the entire union to be larger. Something alone the lines of

```
union foo {
    ...
    char z[sizeof(union foo)];
}
```

except that won't compile, of course, since `union foo`'s size isn't yet known at that point.

Is there a trick that'll let me "fill" the union with a char array?

Comment: Can you please state the purpose of your requirement, so that some alternate solutions can be suggested?

Comment: Well, my original idea was to use this union to implement a sort of "generic" list interface using arrays of this union, and I'd want to have a way to pack binary data as efficiently as possible with such an interface - hence the char array. But I've already thought up a better way to do this that doesn't waste space for *any* type (let alone char[]), so my requirements are moot for the purpose of this question; it's just a curiosity at this point.

Comment: You can always get at the data by casting a union's address to `unsigned char *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a union with everything but the array,

```
union foo_almost {
    int a;
    wchar_t b;
    bar *c;
    baz d;
};
```

Then declare the union with everything,

```
union foo {
    int a;
    wchar_t b;
    bar *c;
    baz d;
    char z[sizeof(union foo_almost)];
};
```

Some folks use macros to do this - declaring the first part as FOO_ALMOST, but all they really save is typing,

```
#def FOO_ALMOST \
    int a; \
    wchar_t b; \
    bar *c; \
    baz d;
union foo_almost {
    FOO_ALMOST
};
```

then,

```
union foo {
    FOO_ALMOST
    char z[sizeof(union foo_almost)];
};
```

Now, sizeof(union foo_almost) and sizeof(union foo) should be the same.  However, your compiler may still allocate more memory than taken by an object of type union foo.

No ugly hacks needed, unless you consider the additional type union foo_almost to be ugly.

Notice,

```
union foo_almost fa;
union foo f;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(fa));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is:

```
union bar {
    union foo {
        int a;
        wchar_t b;
        bar *c;
        baz d;
    } f;
    char z[sizeof(union foo)];
};
```

which gets the right size, however you have to stick in the `f.` when accessing the other members.

AFAIK there is no way of doing this without the `f`.  There may be a better solution to your problem though, as user1969104 suggests.

Here is an ugly hack:

```
#define UNION_FOO_Z(u) ( *(unsigned char (*)[sizeof(union foo)])&u )
```

Usage:

```
union foo f;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof UNION_FOO_Z(f));
```

This hack may have alignment problems (although unlikely).